# How to run a private Stack Exchange-like site?

Tags: discussion, so-enterprise

Is the software on which Stack Exchange is based available so you can set up your own, private SE-like site? Or is there other software available to set up a similar site?

I would like to propose setting up a SE-like internal site at my work place, as a way of documenting the company's software frameworks, workflow practices and so. I think focusing on concrete questions will be more light-weight than writing full-blown documentation; but I also think some software is needed to manage things better than what's possible with mailing lists or a plain wiki.

Comment: AFAIK, SO doesn't offer this except for huge companies with really huge budgets. Take a look at the list of clones: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes! Stack Overflow now offers a feature-complete, privately-hosted version of Stack Overflow so developer teams can securely and privately document their internal frameworks and methodologies Q&A-style. See

### [Stack Overflow Enterprise is now available!](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)

Stack Overflow Enterprise is privately hosted on-premises (or on a secure cloud network) to help teams collaborate, move faster, and share knowledge amongst themselves in a secure environment.  You can request a demo or contact the Enterprise Team through the **[Stack Overflow Enterprise website](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)** to learn more.

Comment: Transparent price estimates would be good. JS

Answer (score 62):

I was disappointed by the official answer so I kept googling around. You may be interested in this question that lists alternatives

[Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/web-applications-inspired-by-stack-exchanges-system)

This is also mentioned in the comments above by Pekka. I think this response deserves more visibility.